# How to turn an array from command line into an array of integers?

Tags: c, arrays, command-line-arguments

I'd like to know how I can turn arrays such as `{33,44,77,88}` or `{10,20,30}`, that are given given as command line arguments, and turn them from a char to an integer and finally put them into an array of integers.

I've been looking for hours and I cannot find an example where they get the array from the command line and turn it into an integer array.

This is what I had placed at the command line `FOO {33,44,77,88} {10,20,30}`

My first 4 lines look like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
```

Comment: 1) How do you make an array of integers? 2) How do you convert one string into an integer? 3) How do you convert several strings into integers?

Comment: Do any of the solutions work for you? if not, please comment as to what else you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will interpret any arguments starting with '{' and pull any numbers out that are comma delimited.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

long int* processArray(char* input, int* lng){
  int length = 0, i = 0;
  while (input[i] != '\0'){
    if (input[i] == ',') length ++;
    i++;
  }
  if (length > 0) length ++;

  input++;

  int j = 0;
  long int * out = malloc(length * sizeof(long int));
  while(*input != '}'){
    while(*input != '\0' && !isdigit(*input)) input++;
    if (!isdigit(*input)) break;
    out[j++] = strtol(input, &input, 10);
  }
  *lng = j;

  return out;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  int i;
  for ( i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    // check for variables that look like arrays
    if (argv[i][0] == '{'){
      printf("Processing '%s'\n", argv[i]);
      int l, j;
      long int * variables = processArray(argv[i], &l);
      printf("Got Array: { ");
      for (j = 0; j < l; j++){
        printf("%ld%s", variables[j], j == l-1? "" : ", ");
      }
      printf(" }\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
./array-args '{ 1, 2, 3 }'
Processing '{1, 2, 3}'
Got Array: { 1, 2, 3 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing in command-line arguments will pass them in as strings and only strings. Therefore, your `argv` array will look like this: `argv = {"./prog", "FOO", "{33,44,77,88}", "{10,20,30}"};`. This means that your passed in array will need to be parsed by your program in order to convert it into an integer array. Try using functions like `strtok` to parse a string based on a delimiter. Then, once you get the individual numbers, i.e. you have parsed "33", you can use `atoi` to convert this string into an integer. You will need to build your array up manually.

Answer (score -1):

i didnt understand your question to 100% but the implementation of what ever you gave will be like this

- args.cpp:

  ```
  #include<iostream>

  using namespace std;

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])

  {

     for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)

   {

          std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;

   }

  return 0;

  }
  ```
- compilation and output :

~/c++practise>g++ args.cpp
~/c++practise> ./a.out {33,44,77,88} {10,20,30}

./a.out

33

44

77

88

10

20

30

Comment: The question is tagged as C, this answer uses C++ - which is a different language